# I want to create an expansion effect using CSS in the following container

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to make it such that when I hover over a single box it's height increases in the same space and other boxes shrink in height.
I have used flex to declare the boxes.
[Div Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiluE.png)

The css i have used is as follows:

```
.projectUpdate{
  height: 66.6%;
}
.hoverBoards{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.hoverBoard{
  height: 33.3%;
}
```

Here the hoverBoards is the external container and hoverBoard is each box. On hover i add the projectUpdate class and remove it on mouseout

Earlier I did use grid and change the grid-row-start to make this effect and it worked but i was not able to add transition to the change in height(I used `transition:all` but it didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css pseudo class `:hover`

Only use javascript if you need to do other things programatically.

So, the parent (or wrapper/container) of the list, need to have fixed height. Then change your `.projectUpdate` into `.hoverboard:hover`.

Example using CSS only:

---

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #232323;
  height: 300px;
}
.hoverBoards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #999999;
  height: 80%;
}
.hoverBoard {
  height: 33.3%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: .3s;
}
.hoverBoard:hover {
  height: 66.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hoverBoards">
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      Capt.io
    </div>
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      HactoberFest Analyzer
    </div>
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      BlockFin
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you need javascript, you can do almost the same.

[Example using JS](https://jsfiddle.net/vsxg5Lzm/57/) :

---

```js
const hoverBoards = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverBoard");

const hoverIn = (ev) => {
  ev.target.classList.add("projectUpdate");
  console.log("class added");
}

const hoverOut = (ev) => {
  ev.target.classList.remove("projectUpdate");
  console.log("class removed");
}

hoverBoards.forEach(hB => {
    console.log("attaching listeners");
  // hover in
  hB.addEventListener("mouseenter", hoverIn);
  // hover out
  hB.addEventListener("mouseleave", hoverOut);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #232323;
  height: 300px;
}

.hoverBoards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #999999;
  height: 80%;
}

.hoverBoard {
  height: 33.3%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: .3s;
}

 .projectUpdate {
  height: 66.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hoverBoards">
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      Capt.io
    </div>
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      HactoberFest Analyzer
    </div>
    <div class="hoverBoard">
      BlockFin
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just didn't understand one thing why didn't adding the class work using javascript. I think i did the same thing. Is there a difference please tell. (P.S. thank u for the answer it worked)

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh take a look at my example using js, adding the class did work using js. Have you tried adding fixed height for parent div?